# How scroll in elasticsearch handles continually updating data?

Tags: indexing, scroll, elasticsearch, reindex

[Here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/reindex.html) is an example with reindexing. But what if `date` field is updating during reindex? And after several scroll requests I need to set date inteval from `date` to `now`. How elasticsearch scroll handle this situation: it just scroll documents with old `date` value or scroll forever untill update requests ends?

Answer (score 2):

The way the scan-and-scroll API works is described one link away from your link, i.e. at http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scan-scroll.html

On that page, it's stated that

> A scrolled search takes a snapshot in time — it doesn’t see any changes 
>   that are made to the index after the initial search request has been 
>   made. It does this by keeping the old datafiles around, so that it can 
>   preserve its “view” on what the index looked like at the time it started.

So what this implies is that whether you use a specific date for your end date or simply `now`, it won't make any difference since the snapshot of documents taken into account by your scroll query will always be constant during the whole time the query runs.

Say you're issuing a scroll query right now (e.g. at 2015-05-11 06:22:27), then no new documents contributed to your index after that date will ever be returned.